# Angular: Showing HTML on mouse enter and left of the element?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to show some HTML on mouse-enter and then have it disappear on mouse-leave. The html needs to appear just left of the element.

Anyone know the best way of implementing this in Angular

Is there a directive that already exists that lets me do this ?

Thanks

Comment: `ng-mouseenter` `ng-mouseleave` `ng-mouseover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing a simple example here. It may help you.

```
//in controller
$scope.showHtml = false;

// Html

<div ng-mouseover="showHtml= true" ng-mouseleave="showHtml= false" style="float:left"></div>
<input type = "button" ng-show="showHtml" value="mybutton">
```

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/GkarV/661/